# Laravel count users by role

Tags: laravel

i'm using entrust package
Basically I just want to count users based on roles something like this:

```
    $users = User::whereHas('roles')->count();
    dd($users);
```

naturally what i'm getting is the count of users with roles, but what i'm trying to get is something like this..

**expected**

```
**roles          count**

 admin             4
 user              2
$role_name     $User_withthisRole_count
```

**Edited:**
i want something dynamic, i don't want to add roles manually

not sure what to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to do a raw query, thanks all for the help

```
DB::select( DB::raw("select name,count(name) AS count,display_name from roles a,
role_user b where a.id=b.role_id group by name") )
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```php
$roles = Role::withCount('users')->get();
foreach($roles as $role) {
    // $role->users_count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = User::where('roles','user')->count();
$admins = User::where('roles','admin')->count();
```

Comment: i want something more dynamic, i don't want to add roles manually, the result should be based on {{ $role->display_name }}

Answer (score 1):

Use [Laravel groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

```
User::select('roles', DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
->groupBy('roles')
->get();
```

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles' in 'field list'

Comment: what is the column name for **roles**

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
    $roles = Role::pluck('name');

    foreach ($roles as $roleName) {
        $userCount = User::whereHas('roles', function($query) use($roleName) {
            $query->where('name', $roleName);
        })->count();
    }
```

Comment: your answer got me closest as much as I've found, still there were error Unknown column 'roles' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `roles` = (select * where `name` = admin))

Comment: Maybe you need to add this: `$roles = Role::pluck('name')->toArray();`. According to entrust documentation, you also may do this `$admins = User::withRole('admin')->get();
// or maybe with a relationsship
$company->users()->withRole('admin')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`$roles = User::where('role_id',$roles->id)->count();`

My relation is a one to many